# Rails: Is the NoMethodError undefined error linked to belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to

My models are as follows:

```
    class Project < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :workspace
      has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
    end

    class Task < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :person
      belongs_to :project
    end

    class Person < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :company
      has_many :tasks
    end
```

So as you can see, each task belongs to a project.  In addition to this, each task has a person attached to it (who is responsible for the task).  In my task model I have a project_id and a person_id.

In my Tasks#Index view I receive a NoMethodError.  In the Index view this is what is causing the error:

```
    <% @task.each do |t| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= t.person.id %></td>
```

The exact error is "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass".

Are my associations incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if the associations are correct. If they weren't, your error message would have complained about a `task` having no method called `person`.

Instead, the message tells you that `t.person` is actually `nil`. I assume that `@task` is actually some collection of tasks; at least one of them seems to be missing a person.

If you think every task should definitely have a person, I'd have a look at my data using either the rails console or a GUI for your database. Alternatively, use the safe access operator `t&.person&.id` which will avoid this error and show you what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You have a task in your database that is not linked to a person. This means that your database currently:

1. Allows `tasks.person_id` to be `null`.
2. Has no foreign_key to `people` table on `tasks.person_id`
3. Combination of 1 and 2

See Rails migration guide regarding foreign keys [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys).

Solution:

- Find the task without a person: `Task.includes(:person).all.select { |t| t.person.nil? }`, delete these tasks or assign an existing person to them
- Add a migration fixing your database, make sure `person_id` is a foreign key and is not nullable.

(First point could be substituted with a `LEFT JOIN` SQL query if you had a lot of tasks, I am assuming it is not the case).